# SQL Merge Rows Into a CSV But Selecting Certain Data Types Rather Than All Table Data

Tags: sql, csv, join, sql-server-2008-r2, union

In SQL Server 2008 R2 is there a way to create a comma delimited output of something like this example table by selecting only specific AttributeIDs

Table:

```
EntryID | AttributeID | Description
===================================================
1       | 5           | OrgName
1       | 15          | OrgDescription
1       | 25          | OrgEmail
1       | 26          | FieldName
2       | 5           | OrgName
2       | 15          | OrgDescription
3       | 5           | OrgName
3       | 26          | FieldName
```

Selecting all EntryIDs, but only Selecting AttributeIDs 5, 15, 25 (not 26)

Desired Example Output:

```
EntryID | Description
===================================================
1       | OrgName,OrgDescrption,OrgEmail
2       | OrgName,OrgDescrption,
3       | OrgName,
```

I can get an output of the entire table in this comma delimited format with the following query, but it includes all AttributeIDs. Is there a place within this query block where I can specify something like Select and combine only AttributeIDs 5, 15, 25 and exclude all other AttributeIDs? Or is there a simpler way without using the XML stuff?

```
(SELECT EntryID, Description = 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Description
           FROM Table b 
           WHERE b.EntryID = a.EntryID
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM Table a
GROUP BY EntryID)
```

Output displaying all data (undesired):

```
EntryID | Description
===================================================
1       | OrgName,OrgDescrption,OrgEmail,FieldName
2       | OrgName,OrgDescrption,
3       | OrgName,FieldName
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `AND AttributeID IN (5,15,25)` inside the `STUFF`:

```
SELECT EntryID, Description = 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Description
           FROM Table b 
           WHERE b.EntryID = a.EntryID
           AND b.AttributeID IN (5,15,25)
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') --Change to 1,1 unless you need to skip two chars
                                        --Or if you want a space after the commas ', '
FROM Table a
GROUP BY EntryID
```

`STUFF` is pretty much the way to do this in SQL Server 2008.